# Find txt files in a Folder with matlab and save plot as jpg

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have the followinf situation. I have in a folder different *.txt files that contains numeric data. I'd like to save the picture of the out coming plot in a jpg file.
The pseudocode would be something like this.

```
while(! more  *.txt files in the folder)
{
   plot(data)
   save_plot_data(plot1.jpg)
}
```

Best regards

Comment: I've solved the problem.
The main problem of "dir" command is that only gets the files of the current directory where you run the command e.g  "*.txt".
My problem was that I had a general folder with different subfolders where  *.txt files where located, so I had to do it recursively.
I found on internet a code that works perfectly and I'd like to share with everyone. This is the link to the page
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15505-recursive-dir 
You can download this program and run in this way:

files_txt_path_ = dirrec('C:\GRAPH_Data','.txt');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
files = dir('*.txt');

for i=1:numel(files)
   h = plot(load(files(i).name));
   saveas(h,sprintf('plot%d.jpg',i),'jpg');
end
```

Best